# Is there a way to write this piece of code smartly?

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I am writing a code for a data set, with 7 different data set, `a1,a2,...,a7`. the dimension of each data set is different. I would like to compute the correlation matrix and then get their mean.

```
A1 = get_corr(a1)
A2 = get_corr(a2)
A3 = get_corr(a3)
A4 = get_corr(a4)
A5 = get_corr(a5)
A6 = get_corr(a6)
A7 = get_corr(a7)

A_mean = [np.mean(A1),np.mean(A2),np.mean(A3),
             np.mean(A4),np.mean(A5),np.mean(A6),
             np.mean(A7)]
```

Is there a way to write this piece smarter?
Ps. I guess one way is to put `A=[a_1,a_2,...,a_7]`, then by using a while loop

```
A_c = []
for i in len(A):
    A_c.append(get_corr(A[i]))
A_mean =[]
for i in len(A_c):
    A_mean.append(np.mean(A_c[i])
```

I would be thankful if you think is it smart or no?

Comment: `data = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7]; A_mean = [np.mean(get_corr(a)) for a in data]`?

Comment: Yes, using a list is one smart way to replace numbered variables.

Comment: Don't use variables called `A1`, `a1`, `A2`, etc. Create lists called `A` and `a`. Then you can do `for i, v in enumerate(a): A[i] = get_corr(v)` .

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible approaches: 
The first, use multiple assignments:

```py
A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7 = get_corr(a1),get_corr(a2),get_corr(a3),get_corr(a4),get_corr(a5),get_corr(a6),get_corr(a7)
A_mean = [np.mean(A1),np.mean(A2),np.mean(A3),
             np.mean(A4),np.mean(A5),np.mean(A6),
             np.mean(A7)]
```

The second ( and more pythonic ) is list comprehension:

```py
items = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7]
corrs = [ get_corr(item) for item in items]
means = [ np.mean(corr) for corr in corrs]
```

Comment: Thank you for your smart advice, but I have another question? What if I would like to bootstrap from my data for a number of definite iterations. For example, `A_all = []
for t in range(len(items)):
    A_BS = []
    for i in range(iter):
        idx_BS = np.random.choice(np.shape(items[0])[1], boots)
        A_BS.append(get_corr((items[t][:,idx_BS]).T)) 
    A_all.append(A_BS)`? where iter is number of times we would like to bootsrap and boots is the number of rows is each iterations that it is bootstraped. Can we write this also smarter, or here no?